# How to load webassembly file in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, jwasm

I have compiled the C code using this command `emcc add.c -o js_plumbing.js -s -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['ccall','cwrap'] -s MODULARIZE=1`

This is my Vue component code -

```
 public instance:any = {
      ready: new Promise(resolve => {
        Module({
          onRuntimeInitialized() {
            this.instance = Object.assign(this, {
              ready: Promise.resolve()
            });
            resolve();
          }
        });
      })
    };


    public draw_outline() {
       this.instance.ready
      .then(_ => this.result_web = this.instance.addTwoNumbers(2,2));
    }
```

draw_outline is getting called when I click on a text element.

And this is the error I'm getting - 
[image]

So after this error I went to generate file and just added export to the module and this error disappears. but now my function in C "addTwoNumbers" is not getting called from instance.

[image]

if I print the value of instance I get [image]
Does anyone know how to proceed from here?

Comment: its probably best to debug from the browser, as the error doesn't seem to be generated from the piece of code pasted

Comment: Do you have some approach in mind? I'm new to wasm and have been on this for 2 days.

Comment: Go to developer tools (F12), inside source tab search for your project files, put breakpoint and debug

Comment: if you are using chrome then you can install Vue.js devtools, and can step through your code as well

Comment: Okay, I shall try that. But do you have any views regarding the last screenshot? I mean what is that output or what do you think it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that when compiling I needed to use `USE_ES6_IMPORT_META=0` flag so that WebAssembly module will use an older version of the import.meta.url line of code for systems that don't recognize the import style. so the command looks like `emcc add.c -o js_plumbing.js -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['ccall','cwrap'] -s ENVIRONMENT='web,worker' -s EXPORT_ES6=1 -s MODULARIZE=1 -s USE_ES6_IMPORT_META=0`

This is my updated code -

```
 Module().then(myModule => {  
        const result = myModule.ccall('addTwoNumbers',
            'number',
            ['number', 'number'],
            [4, 6]);
         console.log("Value from wasm file", result);
        });
```

My config file -

```
const path = require('path');
const contentBase = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..');

module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: config => {

        config.devServer = {
            before(app) {
                // use proper mime-type for wasm files
                app.get('*.wasm', function (req, res, next) {
                    var options = {
                        root: contentBase,
                        dotfiles: 'deny',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/wasm'
                        }
                    };
                    res.sendFile(req.url, options, function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            next(err);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }   
    },
}
```

It is inside a function that I call on a click event . I can elaborate the whole process if someone is interested. It should not take this much time for anyone, I hope it helps others who have been looking for the solution. I realise I have not properly stated the problem in this post, I shall update everything here in a proper way soon.